# Java 1.4 Sort Files - Recent & Latest

Tags: java, java1.4

I'm having Java 1.4 version and need to sort the files by last modified. Sometimes I need to do it by recent and sometimes do it by oldest. I am not sure since Java 1.4 older version can be used in that project

```
File directory = new File("c:\\books\\");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Comment: Wait. You're running Java 1.4?!

Comment: @MCEmperor enterprise or low budget settings use the darnest things. Been there, done that.

Comment: You can define a `Comparator` for each sort strategy.  You can then pass this to `Arrays.sort(Object[], Compator)` to sort the array.  Word of caution - Java 1.4 ceased to be supported nearly 10 years ago.

Comment: @vsfDawg can you please help me with a source code?

Comment: @knittl Doesn't help since it uses diamond operator which is being introduced only in latest java versions. Please advice

Comment: Out of curiosity: what sort of project invests in writing Java 1.4 code, instead of moving the project to a newer java?

Comment: @MCEmperor Yes, i am working with Java 1..4 the older version since the application supports only 1.4 JDK version

Comment: @GhostCat I was been an expert in java recent versions and structures and not sure about old code which can be used for sorting this or achieving this. Please don't mistake or think i don't the java code

Comment: @GhostCat There are lot of references I went through but couldn't find an example to work with old code base

Comment: @javaexpert I don't know what you are referring to with diamond operator. I assume you are talking about the duplicate question? It's accepted answer does not contain the diamond operator and works with Java 1.4. Besides, removing 2 characters is really not too much to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For java 1.2 or higher:

```
    File directory = new File("c:\\books\\");
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            File a1=(File)o1;
            File a2=(File)o2;
            if (a1.lastModified() < a2.lastModified())
                return -1;
            else if (a1.lastModified() > a2.lastModified())
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you really mean 1.2 or higher? It says syntax is invalid - < is invalid. I suspect diamond operator is invalid since it was introduced in higher version than 1.5 or 1.6

Comment: @javaexpert, thanks for pointing out, modified my code. Please let us know if it works.

Comment: i want the descending...How should i do it....that is reverse....oldest first and newest second

Comment: You can replace `return -1` to `return 1` & vice versa. I think this will reverse your order.

Comment: @javaexpert Implementing a Comparator is nothing Java-1.4-specific. It works exactly the same in the latest versions (except for the generic type parameters; the logic is identical)