# Simplify a switch statement to avoid code duplication

Tags: java, java-8, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```java
String fullName = "";
switch(name) {
  case "name1":
    fullName = String.format("%s %s", name, "surname1");
    break;

  case "name2":
    fullName = String.format("%s %s", name, "surname2");    
    break;

  case "name3":
    fullName = String.format("%s %s", name, "surname3");
    break;
  ...
}
```

(there's a break statement after the cases, I just haven't written it here)

So here's the problem:

There's 16 different case statements all having the exact same code, except for the argument to `String.format()`.

Is there any way I can simplify this code?

---

Note: Java 8 is a must

Comment: Use a `Map<String, String>` to look up the format string? (Unfortunately it's hard to tell whether that would work with only pseudo-code. We don't need to see the *actual* business code, but you should be able to come up with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: You mean <case-check> as key and arg to format as value?

Comment: @justanotherguy You need to show what your formatting string *and* arguments look like.

Comment: And if you are bound to a particular Java version, you'll need to mention that in your question as well.

Comment: Does that mean that you are running Java 8 (i.e. language features for Java versions > 8 cannot be used)?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: With your specific example, you could have a `Map<String, String>` where the keys would be "name1" -> "surname1", "name2" -> "surname2" and "name3" -> "surname3". But are the differences *really* just constants?

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes, and no. The application actually converts the syntax of the old style input lines to new. So, the surname part (which isn't actually the surname), that actually comes from a list holding the changed attributes of the line.

Comment: @justanotherguy: That doesn't really tell me whether it's suitable to be in a map... it sounds like what you've shown still isn't *actually* representative of what you need.

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry man. I am trying my best, but I fear that I might accidentally disclose privileged information about the program. That is why I am trying to be as abstract as possible.

Comment: All I can say is this, @MCEmperor is very close to what is actually happening. The only thing left now is what to do when some names are to be appended with a middle name too along with the surname, while some names have 3 surnames (that's a valid possibility here in my country)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if all of your cases have that exact form, then you could simply do something like this:

```java
String surname;
switch (name) {
    case "name1":
        surname = "surname1";
        break;
    case "name2":
        surname = "surname2";
        break;
    default:
        surname = "";
        break;
}
String fullname = String.format("%s %s", name, surname);
```

Or use a `Map` to look up the value:

```java
Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
mapping.put("name1", "surname1");
mapping.put("name2", "surname2");
mapping.put("name3", "surname3");

String surname = mapping.get(name); // Assuming name is always a valid map entry
String fullname = String.format("%s %s", name, surname);
```

Comment: As a side note, using `String.format(…)` this way, is like using an airplane to get to the supermarket. There’s no reason not to use a straight-forward `name + " " + surname`

Comment: @Holger, I know but the standards for the code quality in my company are weird. Using format and/or stringbuilders is a must, so is making every freaking varialbe (even the local ones for that matter) final!

Comment: @justanotherguy would be interesting to know whether they have an explanation for this rule. It’s likely either, fuzzy or outright wrong.

Comment: @justanotherguy I assumed that the example you mentioned was simplified, so I left `String.format(…)` as-is. Turns out it isn't, and instead, it's because of your company's code style standards. Which makes me as curious as Holger is to the reason *why*.

Comment: @MCEmperor, there's a bigger question at large... Why java 8 and not 11?!

Comment: @justanotherguy Or 17, since that's an LTS release. But I've seen worse. Recently, I came across [someone using Java 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72185256/java-1-4-sort-files-recent-latest#comment127539011_72185256). Wow.

Comment: True, though I am guessing it will be a while before 17 is adopted commercially on a large scale. Companies usually buy licenses for at least a decade, and well don't want to let that go to waste ;)

Answer (score 5):

The `Map` approach outlined elsewhere is probably your best best for Java 8, but note that as of Java 14, you can use a switch expression:

```
String surname = switch (name) { 
    case "name1" -> "surname1";
    case "name2" -> "surname2";
    ...
};
String fullName = String.format("%s %s", name, surname);
```